# Lambda expression for Order List of collection of objects based on a property of the object in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

**My Requirement**

Based on a value I need to order a list which has a collection of lists of an object.

The comparison to be done to order the list of lists of an object is to check a property within the object with a predefined value.

*Example*

```
ListAll =  {List1<sig>,List2<sig>,List3<sig>}
```

- Say the object `sig` has properties `key, name, value`
- Each List - `List1<sig>,List2<sig>,List3<sig>` - will be having the same value for the property say `key`

  i.e

  ```
        all `sig` objects inside `List1` will have key value as 501
  ```

  all `sig` objects inside `List2` will have key value as 505

  ```
         all `sig` objects inside `List3` will have key value as 249.
  ```

For the comparison value, I have a string array say `keys[] = {505,501,249}`

*Expected Result*

The resultant order in the list `ListAll` should be such that the lists should be ordered by the value of the property `key`as the order that exists in the array `keys[]`
So the order should like this:

```
List2
List1
List3
```

**My Problem**

How to order the List of Lists of objects using the order of values inside the array.

Comment: Hello. So what problem / error are you having?

Comment: Instead List of Lists you can use SortedDictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done as follows:

```
listAll = listAll.OrderBy(e => Array.IndexOf(keys, e.FirstOrDefault()?.key))
                 .ToList();
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zqD0Ac)

Comment: Like this answer too! And we can make it even a small bit better by extracting the keys array with Linq too! var keys = listAll.Select(item => item.First()).Select(item => item.key).OrderBy(item => item).ToArray();

Answer (score 0):

I quess you could first flatten the list with `SelectMany` from Linq to than order that and regroup.

Something like this

```
public class Item
{
  public int Key {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    List<List<Item>> AllList = new List<List<Item>>();

    AllList.Add(new List<Item>() { new Item(){ Key = 503, Name = "A" }, new Item(){ Key = 503, Name = "B" }, new Item(){ Key = 503, Name = "C" }});
    AllList.Add(new List<Item>() { new Item(){ Key = 500, Name = "A" }, new Item(){ Key = 500, Name = "B" }, new Item(){ Key = 500, Name = "C" }});
    AllList.Add(new List<Item>() { new Item(){ Key = 204, Name = "A" }, new Item(){ Key = 204, Name = "B" }, new Item(){ Key = 204, Name = "C" }});

    var result = AllList.SelectMany(item => item).OrderBy(item => item.Key).GroupBy(item => item.Key);

    foreach(var item in result)
      foreach(var innerItem in item)
        Console.WriteLine(innerItem.Key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that each list has at least 1 element in it, you could do:

```
listAll =  listAll.OrderBy(e => e.First().key).ToList();
```

If you do not know that, you can use `FirstOrDefault` and apply some logic that corresponds with your empty list handling decision.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the order by as below to sort the lists based on their key value. (You don't need another array with their keys)

```
var sortedList = allList.OrderBy(lst => lst.FirstOrDefault()?.Key).ToList();
```

Below is a complete working example,

```
namespace ConsoleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lst1 = new List<Sig>()
            {
                new Sig
                {
                    Key=501,
                    Value="value 501"
                },
                new Sig
                {
                    Key=501,
                    Value="another value 501"
                }
            };

            var lst2 = new List<Sig>()
            {
                new Sig
                {
                    Key=505,
                    Value="value 505"
                },
                new Sig
                {
                    Key=505,
                    Value="another value 505"
                }
            };

            var lst3 = new List<Sig>()
            {
                new Sig
                {
                    Key=502,
                    Value="value 502"
                },
                new Sig
                {
                    Key=502,
                    Value="another value 502"
                }
            };

            var allList = new List<List<Sig>>()
            {
                lst1,lst2,lst3
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Original list:");
            PrintList(allList);

            var sortedList = allList.OrderBy(lst => lst.FirstOrDefault()?.Key).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("Sorted List");
            PrintList(sortedList);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void PrintList(List<List<Sig>> allList)
        {
            foreach (var lst in allList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("List 1");
                foreach (var l in lst)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Key:{l.Key} Value:{l.Value}");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Sig
    {
        public int Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```